# how can I login anonymously with ftp (/usr/bin/ftp)?

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server which allows anonymous access, I don't know how to specify the appropriate username/password required to do this though.

I've tried using anonymous/anonymous as the user/pass with no luck, as well the empty string and various combinations of the two, etc.

It's gotta be something simple that I'm missing, I can use connect just fine with `curl ftp://server/`

Using python:

```
stu@sente ~ $ cat - | python
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.server")
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect()
ftp.login()
list = ftp.nlst()
ftp.close()
print "\n", " ".join(list)
^D

*get* '220 ftp.server NcFTPd Server (licensed copy) ready.\r\n'
*resp* '220 ftp.server NcFTPd Server (licensed copy) ready.'
*cmd* 'USER anonymous'
*put* 'USER anonymous\r\n'
*get* '331 Guest login ok, send your complete e-mail address as password.\r\n'
*resp* '331 Guest login ok, send your complete e-mail address as password.'
*cmd* 'PASS **********'
*put* 'PASS **********\r\n'
*get* '230 Logged in anonymously.\r\n'
*resp* '230 Logged in anonymously.'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type okay.\r\n'
*resp* '200 Type okay.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (12,161,242,12,128,138)\r\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (12,161,242,12,128,138)'
*cmd* 'NLST'
*put* 'NLST\r\n'
*get* '150 Data connection accepted from 208.118.225.99:38451; transfer starting.\r\n'
*resp* '150 Data connection accepted from 208.118.225.99:38451; transfer starting.'
*get* '226 Listing completed.\r\n'
*resp* '226 Listing completed.'

Obin bin pub public sci_tech_med
```

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something?  The listing looks like it connected just fine.

Comment: I concur.  That looks just like what you would want.  Of course, it will most likely be read-only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Anonymous FTP usage is covered by **[RFC 1635: How to Use Anonymous FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1635)**:

> ### What is Anonymous FTP?
>
> Anonymous FTP is a means by which archive sites allow general access
> to their archives of information.  These sites create a special
> account called "anonymous".
>
> …
>
> Traditionally, this special anonymous user account accepts any string
> as a password, although it is common to use either the password
> "guest" or one's electronic mail (e-mail) address.  Some archive
> sites now explicitly ask for the user's e-mail address and will not
> allow login with the "guest" password.  Providing an e-mail address
> is a courtesy that allows archive site operators to get some idea of
> who is using their services.

These are general recommendations, though. **Each FTP server may have its own guidelines.**

For **sample use of the `ftp` command** on anonymous FTP access, see [appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1635#appendix-A):

```
atlas.arc.nasa.gov% ftp naic.nasa.gov
Connected to naic.nasa.gov.
220 naic.nasa.gov FTP server (Wed May 4 12:15:15 PDT 1994) ready.
Name (naic.nasa.gov:amarine): anonymous
331 Guest login ok, send your complete e-mail address as password.
Password:
230-----------------------------------------------------------------
230-Welcome to the NASA Network Applications and Info Center Archive
230-
230-     Access to NAIC's online services is also available through:
230-
230-        Gopher         - naic.nasa.gov (port 70)
230-    World-Wide-Web - http://naic.nasa.gov/naic/naic-home.html
230-
230-        If you experience any problems please send email to
230-
230-                    naic@nasa.gov
230-
230-                 or call +1 (800) 858-9947
230-----------------------------------------------------------------
230-
230-Please read the file README
230-  it was last modified on Fri Dec 10 13:06:33 1993 - 165 days ago
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
ftp> cd files/rfc
250-Please read the file README.rfc
250-  it was last modified on Fri Jul 30 16:47:29 1993 - 298 days ago
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> get rfc959.txt
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for rfc959.txt (147316 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
local: rfc959.txt remote: rfc959.txt
151249 bytes received in 0.9 seconds (1.6e+02 Kbytes/s)
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
atlas.arc.nasa.gov%
```

See also [the example session at the University of Edinburgh site](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/tasks/ftp2.4.2.1.1.html).

Answer (score 42):

Anonymous ftp logins are usually the username 'anonymous' with the user's email address as the password.  Some servers parse the password to ensure it looks like an email address.

```
User:  anonymous
Password:  anonymous@domain.com
```

Comment: In password should I provide an actual e-mail address?

Comment: Generally it only needs to be something in the syntactic form of an email address.

Answer (score 2):

As others point out, the user name is usually *anonymous*, and the password is usually your e-mail address, but this is not universally true, and has been found not to work for certain anonymous FTP sites.  For example, at least some **cPanel** sites seem to deviate from the norm, and if given the traditional user name without domain, one of various errors may result:

> If the server uses Pure-FTP as the FTP server:
>
> ```
> 421 Can't change directory to /var/ftp/ error message.
> ```
>
> If the server uses ProFTP as the FTP server:
>
> ```
> 530 Login Authentication Failed error message.
> ```

When one of the aforementioned errors occurs when attempting anonymous access, try including a domain with the username.  For example, where *example.com* is  the domain used in your e-mail address:

```
User name: anonymous@example.com
```

In the specific case of a **cPanel** site, the password value is unimportant, and may be left blank, but there is no harm in providing a "traditional" anonymous password formatted as an e-mail address.

For reference, this answer is based on content found on a [documentation.cpanel.net Anonymous FTP page](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Anonymous+FTP).  At the time of this writing, it stated:

> When users log in to FTP anonymously, they **must** format usernames
>   as `anonymous@example.com`, where `example.com` represents the user's
>   domain name. This requirement directs your server to the correct
>   `public_ftp` directory.